# Rendering issue in chartview graph in qml

Tags: graph, qml, qqmlcomponent, qchartview, qqmlengine

I am having chart view and I am trying to change font pixel size of  y axis values  based on rectangles click i am passing parameter to function it has small(i gave 8),medium(9) and large(10).but it is not changing size immediately it is showing 0 below actual value for second and then font is correctly updated
I am having rendering issue in qml.

can someone help me out